# TinyMCE Remove Inserted Image Prefix?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE Laravel File Manager but Im having an issue whenever I add images. Photos I save are saved at public_html/photos, but when I add the images to the tinyMCE editor using Insert > Image. The editor shows a broken image since the src provided has a prefix of laravel-filemanager showing as

```
src="http://localhost:8000/laravel-filemanager/photos/user_icon_add.png"
```

Instead of

```
src="http://localhost:8000/photos/user_icon_add.png"
```

How do I remove the laravel-filemanager prefix for photos that I add?

Here are some configs of my lfm.php

```
'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager',
'base_directory' => 'public_html',
'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
'files_folder_name' => 'files',
'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
'thumb_folder_name' => 'thumbs',
```

Here's my tinyMCE js config

```
var editor_config = {
        path_absolute: "{{ URL::to('/') }}/",
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link charmap print preview hr pagebreak", "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen", "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality", "emoticons paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link",
        style_formats:
            [
                {
                    title: 'Bullet',
                    selector: 'ul',
                    classes: 'browser-default',
                }
            ],
        relative_urls: false,
        file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
            var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            var y = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.grtElementByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
                var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name' + field_name;
            if (type = 'image') {
                cmsURL = cmsURL + '&type=Images';
            } else {
                cmsUrl = cmsURL + '&type=Files';
            }
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file: cmsURL,
                title: 'Filemanager',
                width: x * 0.8,
                height: y * 0.8,
                resizeble: 'yes',
                close_previous: 'no'
            });
        }
    };
    tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `'url_prefix' => '',`  in `lfm.php` ?

Comment: Yes, but then the file-manager would not work because the cmsURL found in the script should match the url_prefix, which would be this line 

var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name' + field_name;

Comment: Is the file `public/js/lfm.js` present in your version?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to edit the route_prefix to var route_prefix = (options && options.prefix) ? options.prefix : '/' However, it still has the laravel-filemanager prefix on the image. It works and does not have the prefix if the folder I use is public, probably part of the code of the laravel file-manager that it does not use prefix if base_directory config is public, not public_html. But since I'm using this on hosting, the public folder has to be name public_html.

Answer (score 0):

The app_url may not be correct in .env.
set your APP_URL in .env file